# Getting all data in a database row to show Android SQLite

Tags: android, database, android-listview, listactivity

I am trying to get my class to show all the data in a database. at the current time it i only showing the one set of data which would be the title and i tried to alter he code to what i thought would show all the data

```
public class WorkoutProgress extends ListActivity {
private DataBaseHelper datasource;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progress);

    datasource = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    datasource.open();
    fillData();
    datasource.close();
}
 private void fillData() {
        // Get all of the notes from the database and create the item list
        Cursor c = datasource.getAllTitles();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_TITLE,DataBaseHelper.KEY_ISBN, DataBaseHelper.KEY_PUBLISHER };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text1 };

        // Now create an array adapter and set it to display using our row
        SimpleCursorAdapter notes =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.notes_row, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(notes);
    }

    }
```

The code I thought I needed to change was this line

```
     String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_TITLE};
```

To this line

```
        String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_TITLE,DataBaseHelper.KEY_ISBN, DataBaseHelper.KEY_PUBLISHER };
```

this is the notes_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TextView android:id="@+id/text1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/text3"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change the `from` array but you must also add some ids in the `to` array(`ids` of other `TextView`s in the list row layout(`R.layout.notes_row`) where you would show the other columns.)

```
String[] from = new String[] { DataBaseHelper.KEY_TITLE,DataBaseHelper.KEY_ISBN, DataBaseHelper.KEY_PUBLISHER };
int[] to = { R.id.text1, R.id.text2, R.id.text3 };
```

where `R.id.text1`, `R.id.text2` and `R.id.text3` are the ids of `TextView` from the `R.layout.notes_row`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: so i would also add more Textviews inside the note_row and then put the new textViews into the 'to' array?

Comment: @DarrenMurtagh Yes, otherwise where should the data be displayed?

Comment: when i change the xml to what had been added above the xml says there is an error

Comment: thank you that has really helped. though quick question. do you know how to get this on the same line as currently each entry is a separate line

Comment: @DarrenMurtagh Remove the `android:orientation="vertical"` from the `LinearLayout` in the xml file.

Comment: thanx thats really helped thought i dont seem to be able to add any labels to the data being displayed? hate asking a third question but is this possible?

Comment: @DarrenMurtagh I don't think I understand what do you mean by label. If you want to put some text before those `TextView`(with data) you could add other `TextView`s in the xml layout(before the `TextView` that your already have) like this: `<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:text="Label here:"/>`